# Selecting Point Features by Distance and Name

Tags: arcmap

I have a multi point Townland file. I want to be able to remove duplicates within a radius of 3000 meters from each individual point??

I cannot simply remove duplicates as they are from various locations.

E.g. There may be five points called Castletown within a 4000m radius and I only want one.

However there may be another five points called Castletown 40,000m away (As more than one area is called Castletown)  and I also only want to keep one of these within a 4000m radius of itself.

Therefore I would end up with two points called Castletown from two separate locations.

Any ideas whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the [Delete Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool using either the shape geometry (if the geometries are identical) or a named field, such as "Casteltown". This will remove all but one of the points. You can test this by using the [Find Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000) tool, which won't delete the data.

The Delete Identical tool also has a tolerance setting, which will allow you to filter by location. This tool is your best bet if you'd like to process an entire point file at once using a standard search tolerance (e.g. the tolerance of 4000m can be applied to all points since no two "Castletowns" are within 4000m of each other).

Note: This tool requires ArcInfo.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this using a Python script.  You would have to iterate over all of the point features and create a 3000m buffer for each one.  If there are multiple Castletowns within that buffer you have a few options to determine which one to keep:

1. Keep the original one.
2. Use the [Central Feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p00000015000000) tool which "Identifies the most centrally located feature in a point, line, or polygon feature class."
3. Use the [Mean Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Mean_Center/005p00000018000000/) tool which "Identifies the geographic center (or the center of concentration) for a set of features."
4. Use the [Median Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Median_Center/005p00000019000000/) tool which "Identifies the location that minimizes overall Euclidean distance to the features in a dataset."

The tools listed above are available for all license levels of ArcGIS.